# Request to merge multiple scripting-related tags

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

There are the similar tags:

- [scripts](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/scripts) and its synonym [script](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/script) (1940 questions)

  **Excerpt:**

  > Script is series of instructions written in plain text file. The script interpreter (i.e. shell, Python, Ruby, etc.) can read this file and act on the instructions as if they were typed at the command prompt. The interpreter also provides a variety of useful programming features to make your scripts truly powerful.

  **Wiki:**

  > A script is a program or sequence of instructions that is interpreted or carried out by another program rather than by the computer processor (as a compiled program is).
  >
  > Some languages have been conceived expressly as script languages. Among the most popular are Perl, REXX (on IBM mainframes), JavaScript, and Tcl/Tk.
- [scripting](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/scripting) (57 questions)

  **Excerpt:**

  > Script is series of instructions written in plain text file. The script interpreter (i.e. shell, Python, Ruby, etc.) can read this file and act on the instructions as if they were typed at the command prompt. The interpreter also provides a variety of useful programming features to make your scripts truly powerful.

  **Wiki:**

  > A script is a program or sequence of instructions that is interpreted or carried out by another program rather than by the computer processor (as a compiled program is).
  >
  > Some languages have been conceived expressly as script languages. Among the most popular are Perl, REXX (on IBM mainframes), JavaScript, and Tcl/Tk.

---

- and maybe even [shell-scripting](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/shell-scripting) (715 questions)

  **Excerpt:**

  > In shell scripting, a shell such as bash runs a  file containing a list of commands (a script). The script is effectively a program and the shell is its interpreter.

  **Wiki:**
  *none*

**I strongly propose to merge at least the first and second point, as they even have exactly the same tag excerpts and wikis!**

Eventually we could even consider also merging the third point into them.

What's your opinion?

Comment: What tag should be the root one?

Comment: @Seth I vote for `script` - the shortest name, failing that, `scripts` with the most questions.

Comment: @Seth I would decide on either `script` or `scripts`, which makes not much difference. Probably `scripts` is used more often and is already the master synonym for `script`.

Comment: I already suggested `scripting` and `shell-scripting` to become [synonyms for `scripts`](http://askubuntu.com/tags/scripts/synonyms).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is done. I have remapped [scripting](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/scripting) and [shell-scripting](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/shell-scripting) to [scripts](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/scripts).

Answer (score 7):

I propose that we merge [shell-scripts](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/shell-scripts) as well. [shell-scripts](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/shell-scripts) by itself is not much more specific than the others. Most, if not all, scripts contain some amount of code run by another language: Awk, Perl, python, to name a common few. We should just additionally tag with the target shell, instead: [bash](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/bash). After all, if the user wants a [csh](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/csh) script, they will tag with that. Why not for bash and the other shells?